# rails active admin overriding my css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

i know this question has been several times,but none of the solutions worked for me

I have a JumboElevator.css.scc file

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Then i have just one page
new.html.erb

It has internal stylesheet

```
.jumbotron {
background: #358CCE;
color: #FFF;
border-radius: 0px;
}
.jumbotron-sm { padding-top: 24px;
padding-bottom: 24px; }
.jumbotron small {
color: #FFF;
}
.h1 small {
font-size: 24px;
}

#error_explanation {
  color: red;
  ul {
    color: red;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  }
}

.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;
  .form-control {
    color: #b94a48;
  }
}

.navbar-brand
{
  padding:2px 5px;
}
.icon
{
  padding:5px;
}
.check_box_type
{
  padding-left:5px;
}
.field_with_errors .form-control {
border-color: #a94442;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
}
.field_with_errors .form-control {
color: #b94a48;
transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
```

After i included active admin,my this internal styling are getting overridden ny active admin stylesheet.

Please can anyone help me

Moving active_admin.css.scss to vendor folder didnt work

All this is happening when deploying to heroku

Comment: check the load order of the scc files .

Comment: No idea how it worked,but i deleted my active_admin.css.scss file and then again moved it to the vendor/assests/stylesheets folder and it started working.No idea why it wasn't working previously

Comment: Another thing if u can help me is,that the reason behind moving my custom css to internal stylesheet in my new.html.erb file was that the JumboElevator.css.scss initially had all that internal styling in it,but heroku was not applying those styling to my app,that is why i had to move all those styling internally to the new.html.erb file